# Settings.Designer file and Staticness

Tags: c#, winforms, settings, data-access-layer

I have a DAL class library that is included in my program as a DLL. The below line is from the DAL to initialize the connection.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet("table");
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(Settings.CMOSQLConn);
```

When I run this I get the below error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in CMO.DAL.dll
```

The below is in the Settings.Designer.cs file and it is where it shows the error on the *get call*:

```
        [global::System.Configuration.ApplicationScopedSettingAttribute()]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [global::System.Configuration.SpecialSettingAttribute(global::System.Configuration.SpecialSetting.ConnectionString)]
    [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("Data Source=WWCSTAGE;Initial Catalog=CMO;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=CMOWe" +
        "bService;Password=ecivreSbeWOMC")]
    public static string CMOSQLConn {
        get {
            return (CMOSQLConn);
        }
    }
```

Anyone have any ideas of what to look for?  Is it because the connection string is stored in the dll instead of my Main App?  I am really stuck on this and will greatly appreciate any help!

### EDIT 1

I tried ***Greg's*** suggestion below:

```
        public static string CMOSQLConn {
        get {
            return (Settings.CMOSQLConn);
        }
    }
```

And I still get the same error...  Any more thoughts?  Thanks so far!

### EDIT 2

So I followed the suggestion of regenerating the settings file below and now my setting file looks like this -->

```
public string CMOSQLConn {
        get {
            return ((string)(this["CMOSQLConn"]));
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately this won't compile now as wherever I have this statement -->

```
            SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(Settings.CMOSQLConn);
```

I now get this error -->

```
Error   1   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'CMO.DAL.Properties.Settings.CMOSQLConn.get'  B:\MyDocs\tmpPATRIOT\Projects\VS2008\DisConnectDAL\CMO.DAL\SupportWorker.cs 13  51  CMO.DAL
```

Is this what I should expect?

Thanks!

Comment: (Don't feel bad, I bet everybody except Jon Skeet himself has made this mistake at least once or twice.  :) )

Comment: How did CMOSQLConn get to be a static property?  When I've generated a connection string in a settings file, it still becomes an instance property.

Comment: I don't know and it is driving me nuts!!!  I manually removed the static and the rest of the library is freaking out looking for an instance now...  This wasn't my original code.  It was a web service in VB that I converted to a C# class library. to use in my WinForm App...

Thanks for your time in this!

Comment: Ooo, you used one of those online converters or something?  Ouch.  :(

Comment: What's the library do? Maybe you'd be better of writing it yourself instead of munging it in like this.  That, or including it as a separate assembly so you don't have to go through one of those rubbish, broken "converters".

Comment: (I have a grudge against converters.  My manager used one, thought it made it so easy, plugged the stuff into our main branch.  I spent the next couple months, on and off, fixing all kinds of weird problems.)

Comment: LOL, I understand your concerns.  The library is the DAL for a portion of our program.  It used to be a vb WebService.  I semi-manually converted it to a Class Library.  I didn't use one of those Project Converters but I did use this --> http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/ to convert chunks of code here and there to save me typing.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be saving you much time at the moment.  ;)  Try regenerating the settings file properly and updating the references to correctly use the settings.  Clearly, the fault lies somewhere in your conversion process.

Comment: Thanks, so Settings Properties are usually NOT Static and I should look to that as a type of barometer in this?

Comment: No, don't manually generate the settings.designer file.  Use an automatically generated one.

Comment: why not Greg D? Manually re-generating it should work - Properties > Settings.settings > Right click menu > Run Custom Tool > verify that static property is gone

Comment: Forgive me, I mis-wrote.  I meant to say, don't manually _write_ the settings.designer file, regenerate it.

Comment: Try Settings.Default.CMOSQLConn (or something similar to that).  You should be able to explore it pretty well with intellisense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a classic c# properties mistake.  Double check what you're returning in your property-- you're returning the property itself!  Name resolution will prefer the local name over an external name.  You're getting a stack overflow because you hit infinite recursion when `CMOSQLConn.get` calls `CMOSQLConn.get`.

Consider returning `Settings.CMOSQLConn`.  The extra specification should clearly indicate the correct location of your connection string.

**EDIT:**

Whoops!  I didn't notice that you pasted that from your Settings designer file.  The infinite recursion is clearly happening, but I'm afraid you'll have to do some more investigation to track down why it's happening in this case.

It appears that your designer file was generated incorrectly (!!!).  On VS2008, my settings designer getters look something like:

```
public bool Foo{
    get {
        return ((bool)(this["Foo"]));
    }
    // ...
}
```

You may need to do something similar.  IE:

```
public string CMOSQLConn
    get {
        return ((string)(this["CMOSQLConn"]));
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Any hints on how to do that?  The Call Stack doesn't seem overly useful as it shows what I already posted!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your code to this:

```
 public static string CMOSQLConn {
        get {
            return ((string)(this["CMOSQLConn"]));
        }
    }
```

Hmm.. Good point in the comments. I just looked in my VS settings file and copied and pasted without thinking. Something isn't right with your settings file... It shouldn't be creating a static property for the settings.

Comment: Can you access this from a static property?

Comment: It says "Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static method, or static field initializer"

Ideas? THanks for the time!